# How to add an object in array in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

I have this schema:

```
var PostSchema = new Schema({
  title: String,
  description: String,
  content: String,
  image: String,
  category: String,
  url: String,
  views: {
    type: Number,
    default: 0
  },
  comments: [
    {
      username: String,
      email: String,
      comment: String
    }
  ]
});
```

Now I need to put new objects in comments array. I've made this method, but obviously it doesn't work :)

```
router.put('/blog/:url/add-comment', (req, res) => {
    let db = req.db
    Post.updateOne({ 'url': req.params.url }, {$push: {comments: {
        'username': req.body.comments.username,
        'email': req.body.comments.email,
        'comment': req.body.comments.comment
    }}})
```

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Why does it not work? What's the error?

Comment: Presumably `req.body.comments` is possibly an "array" within the content being sent/received. In this case it would be `req.body.comments[0].username` etc for each element. Or just `{ $push: { comments: { $each: req.body.comments } } }`. But the necessary detail is really missing from the question, so it should be updated to show what is being sent.